# Picture added to Tkinter program not showing up

Tags: python, tkinter

This is a part of my code:

```
rip = tk.Tk()

f2 = tk.Frame(rip)
f2.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=("nwes"))
f2.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
f2.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
c1=tk.Label(f2, text="feet to meter or meter to feet?")
c1.grid(row=0, column=0)
c2=tk.Label(f2, text='type "ft" for feet to meter, type "m" for meter to feet')
c2.grid(row=1, column=0)
lol = tk.StringVar()
choice = tk.Entry(f2, width=7, textvariable=lol)
choice.grid(row=2, column=0)
b1=tk.Button(f2, text="Confirm", command=choose)
b1.grid(row=3, column=0)
picfile="bgmain.gif"
image = tk.PhotoImage(file=picfile)
w=image.width()
h=image.height()
x=10
y=10
rip.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d"%(w,h,x,y))
panel=tk.Label(rip,image=image)
button=tk.Button(panel, text="button widget")
button.pack(side="top", pady=5)
panel.image=image

rip.mainloop()
```

I'm trying to add background picture to it. No error message and it seems like the picture was called out, because the window size was changed to the size of the picture. But nothing will show up, it's still white on the background.

Comment: Did you check your permissions ?

Comment: you need a panel.pack() I think

Comment: @JoranBeasley: in this case it needs to be `grid`, not `pack`, since the OP is already using `grid` in the `rip` window.

Comment: @JoranBeasley: it's not the same when taken literally. If you mix `pack` and `grid` in the same parent, the GUI typically locks up and uses 100% cpu.

Comment: yeah I know  ... its the same difference figuratively though :P ie thats the reason its not showing up ... I should be more careful with my words ...

Comment: I think the picture needs a master. Can you try `image = tk.PhotoImage(master = rip, file=picfile)`?

Comment: help... I don't know what to do now... I tried master=rip and it's the same, and cant use panel.pack()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have added the image to a label, but you haven't added the label to a window. Since `panel` hasn't been placed on the screen it will be invisible. Since it is invisible, the image in it will also be invisible.

If you're wanting this to be a background image, `place` is a good choice for geometry manager. You can use `place` to set an image to fill its parent like so:

```
panel.place(x=0,y=0, relwidth=1.0, relheight=1.0)
```

You can also use `grid`, though obviously with different arguments. In this specific case you cannot use `pack` since you're already using `grid` in the main window.

Depending on the effect that you want, you might need to change the stacking order. Since you are currently creating `panel` as one of the last things you create, it will likely obscure other widgets since it will "stack" on top of them. The simplest solution is to create your background image first, and then create the widgets that will go on top. Your other choice is to use `panel.lower(0)` to lower the stacking order of `panel`.

Comment: It did make the picture show up, but I think because I used frame, the center part (the frame part) still have the white background and the picture only show up around it, how do I solve that problem?